# Unity Gun Ammo not Decreasing Problem in Multiplayer (Maybe Related To my Multiplayer System: Photon)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I have a problem in which my ammo won't decrease when I shoot until I wait for a certain Amount of time. I'm currently using Photon as my Network System for my game and my gun code from Brackeys (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAx5g9V5bcM&lc=UghlAulu5dH90HgCoAEC). This is maybe related to internet problems and delays but I'll show you the code I use:

```
void Update()
{

    if(!photonView.IsMine) return;

    if (!canShowAmmo)
    {
        ammoText.text = "Ammo: " + currentAmmo;
    }

    if (isStarted && (owner.openPanel || MultiplayerManager.main.roomManager.gameDone))
    {
        if (isScoped)
        {
            Scope();
        }
        return;
    }

    if (currentAmmo <= 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Reload());
        return;
    }
        

    if(autoOrSemi == true){
        if(Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTime){
            nextTime = Time.time + 1f/fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    if(autoOrSemi == false){
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTime){
            nextTime = Time.time + 1f/fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
    {
        Scope();
    }


}

public void Shoot(){
    MuzzleFlash.Play();

    currentAmmo--;

    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(shotSound, transform.position);

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range)){
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

        IDamageable target = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<IDamageable>();

        if (target != null)
        {
            if (hit.collider != owner.GetComponent<Collider>())
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
                owner.score += (int) damage;
                owner.ScoreUpdate();
            }
        }

        if(hit.rigidbody != null){
            hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * impactForce);
        }

        GameObject effect = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
        Destroy(effect, 2f);
    }
}

public IEnumerator Reload(){
    isReloading = true;
    Debug.Log("Reloading");

    canShowAmmo = true;
    ammoText.text = "Reloading...";
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime - .25f);
    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.25f);
    canShowAmmo = false;
    
    currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
    isReloading = false;
}
```

so if I was correct and it's caused by lag or I was wrong and didn't have any relation to the Network, please I need a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you set `canShowAmmo` other than in the function `Reload`? Are you just asking why the text component is not updating? I would think it is because the condition `if (!canShowAmmo)` is not met, so it is not updating the text field.

Comment: So now i will have to delete the canShowAmmo bool?

Answer (score 0):

I think you issue are concurrent Coroutines!

you are doing

```
if (currentAmmo <= 0)
{
    StartCoroutine(Reload());
    return;
}
```

This will start a new routine **every frame** while the condition is met.

You rather want to do e.g.

```
if (!isReloading && currentAmmo <= 0)
{
    StartCoroutine(Reload());
    return;
}

if(isReloading) return;
```

Comment: but when it still is reloading, I can Shoot!

Comment: Try the updated version. Now if you are reloading you can't do anything further ;) you might want to move the scope above though

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, I may just found a solution: just add a new private bool and set it to true inside the if function derHugo presented below or above this comment and if bool is false then shooting is disabled then after reloading inside the enumerator after isReloading = false, make the bool to false

Comment: Hi @FenderSelim, awesome you found a solution, I believe you could greatly increase the readability of your answer by updating the code as you are explaining it in your post.